# Target "own" <script> tag in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Can I get a `<script>` tag element itself inside it's JavaScript code?

```
<script name="George">
   var el = getThisScriptTag(); //pseudo
   console.log( el.getAttribute('name') );
</script>
```

=> this should print "George" to the browser's console.

Please ask any question if something is not clear enaugh :)

Thanks :)

Comment: Duplicate of a duplicate. Is that a statement? :D

Comment: Ah, I wanted to avoid non-standard or "IDing", but thanks for pointing that question out :)